# "What happens when" or "what happen when"?

Tags: grammar

Should I write "what happens when" or "what happen when"? Does it depend on if I know if the "what" that happens is plural or singular, or is it always the same?

Provided "what happens" is correct in all situations, how about this:

> "What happens when [something]? Two things: [one thing that happens] and [another thing that happens]."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find a grammatical rule that explains this, but I do know that *"What happen when"* sounds very wrong. It should be *What happen**s** when*.

Comment: I concur. It seems to me that "what" always has singular agreement. "What happens during a thunderstorm? Lightning strikes happen."

Answer (score 3):

"What" is a pronoun, and you use the third person singular form of the verb, which for most simple verb means a suffix of "s". "What happens" is correct.